# Heroku with Django and node build

Tags: node.js, django, heroku, bitbucket-pipelines

I am pushing everything from BitBucket to Heroku, using Pipelines. The problem are static files because I am using [django-gulp](https://github.com/beaugunderson/django-gulp) which will compile all sass files (using nodejs and gulp) when I call `collectstatic`.

It will first push code to Heroku and run it, but as it turns out all other scripts (pip install, npm install, ...) will execute on BitBucket side, and not Heroku. My `Profile` has this inside:

```
web: gunicorn magistrska_web.wsgi --log-file -
```

Website is running, but there are no static files.

If always run with `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`, otherwise I get the following

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput        
remote:        /bin/sh: 1: gulp: not found
```

What I would need to do is for Heroku to first run `npm install` before collectstatic or it won't work, but I am having hard time finding any documentation on this.

`heroku local web` works fine, because I ran `collectstatic` before locally.

---

`bitbucket-pipelines.yml` configuration:

```
image: nikolaik/python-nodejs

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - npm install
          - npm install -g gulp
          - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was way too easy!

I needed to add another, nodejs buildpack on Heroku and it worked! Example below

[image]